# using RHEL5 as a router

Tags: linux, networking, rhel5, gateway

I am planning to use a RHEL5 installed computer as a internet connection sharing device.

I have installed 2 LAN cards, eth0 and eth1.

eth0: Internet
eth1: LAN

eth0 configuration as follows ;

```
Ipaddress : 115.252.64.187
Subnet :   255.255.255.240
Gateway : 115.252.64.177
```

eth1 configuration:

```
ipaddress : 192.168.1.1
subnet : 255.255.255.0
gateway : 192.168.1.1
```

I wrote the following entries in /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 202.138.96.2
(preferred DNS Server)
nameserver 202.138.103.2
(secondary DNS server)
```

I am confused about which gateway I should use in the above scenario.  I am unable to ping to my LAN and am also unable to connect to the Internet.  How can I configure this server as my gateway?

Answer (score 4):

with regards to routing, you want to have a default gateway (in `/etc/sysconfig/network`) set to your internet gateway.

then create a gateway rule to your local lan (not sure what the topology is so i'd all of them below) on the interface facing the local networks. create a file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1` with the following:

```
10.0.0.0/8 via 192.168.1.1
192.168.0.0/16 via 192.168.1.1
```

and then tell it to act as a router:

```
echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

(obviously set that in /etc/sysctl.conf so it's permanent between reboots).

Hopefully I haven't forgotten anything... :)